# Botframework v4 on Functions

Tags: botframework, azure-functions, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to figure out if I can run botframework v4 on Azure functions. Current azure functions page shows only v3 sdk.

Anyone has any idea if we can run v4 on functions or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to Azure portal,

> Bot Framework SDK v4 is now available and comes with many updates and new functionality. Function Bots are based on SDK v3; we recommend you create a Web App Bot instead, which supports the new SDK v4.

You can set up  a functions bot, but only with the v3 SDK. AFAIK, there are no plans to support functions bots in v4.